# ckeditor custom style for img not showing in dropdown

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have this is my config file:

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'custom_styles', [
    { name: 'Paragraph', element: 'p' },
    { name: 'Heading 3', element: 'h3' },
    { name: 'Heading 4', element: 'h4' },
    { name: 'Marker: Yellow', element: 'span', styles: { 'background-color': 'Yellow' } },
    { name: 'Custom Image', element: 'img', attributes: { 'class': 'myClass' } }
]);
```

but in the dropdown only the first 5 are showing, even when I click on an image. I've tried it in recent Chrome and Firefox and the config is not being cached (I added the yellow style to check that and it works fine). When I click on the image the bottom bar shows "body p image" but the default in the dropdown says "paragraph". I've also tried switching the order of styles around.

Documentation seems straight-forward so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Is there some trick to getting object styles to show up?

EDIT:
There also seems to be something strange going on with other selected parts. I have Image2 plugin and when I add a link to an image then click that image the bottom bar just shows "body p image" and doesn't mention the "a" even though it's there in the HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Images in ckeditor now use a widget system. I'm not sure why this is not really documented yet but the solution is to specify:

- type: widget
- widget: image

So the following should work:

```
{ name: 'Custom Image', type: 'widget', widget: 'image', attributes: { 'class': 'myClass' } }
```

Comment: Hero! saved my day. 

SEO comment; to help others find this answer sooner: "stylesSet not working for img tag / image. attribute image styleset not working / ignores"

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure where you are fuzzy but if you are asking why the option isn't always in the ***styles*** drop-down menu: It's because the behaviour is context-sensitive depending on where the caret is and/or what is currently selected.  Selecting an image allows you to retrospectively apply styles to it via this menu, but not insert new images - for that you'd need to add your own control.

As far as adding classes to objects goes, what you have should work as long as *CKEDITOR* knows about the stylesheet.  Because the content pane of the editor uses an `<iframe>` element, a stylesheet would need to be added to it's respective document.  This can be done via the global config ([docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss)):

```js
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/path/custom.css';
```

...or on an individual editor instance since version 4.4 ([docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-addContentsCss)):

```js
CKEDITOR.instances['myEditorId'].addContentsCss( '/path/custom.css' );
```

Comment: I can successfully add a class to, say, an unordered list, and see that class applied in the HTML-view. But I cannot seem to add a class to an image, even though I'm using the same method. Not sure if this is an Image2 problem.

Comment: Well I was playing around here: http://jsbin.com/qutonuwu/1/edit?js,output - I don't think I can host a stylesheet to include in the config in any JS fiddle but if you simply try adding an image, then selecting custom image and then viewing the source you can see it adds a class as you would expect.

Comment: That works in my browser but it's Image, not Image2 (Enhanced Image).